# ¿Cómo puedo salir de un bucle dada una cadena de caracteres?

Tags: c

estaba haciendo una función que pida al usuario palabras en inglés y su traducción al español y para salir del bucle, el usuario debe escribir la palabra "Fin".

`MAX` y `PAL` son dos constantes, con el valor de `100` y `40` respectivamente donde `MAX` es el máximo de palabras que puede introducir el usuario y `PAL` es el tamaño de la cadena de caracteres.

Las palabras se guardan en el registro siguiente.

```
typedef struct {
    char ingles[PAL];
    char espanol[PAL];
} tDiccionario;
```

Aquí el código.

```
void IntroducirPalabras(tDiccionario *palabras){
    puts("Introduzca 1 palabra en ingles, pulse ENTER, y luego la traduccion en Espanol, si desea no introducir mas, teclee 'Fin'");
    
    int i = 0, fin = 1;

    do{
        if(i > MAX || !fin)
            printf("\nFin.\n");
        else{
            printf("\nIntroduzca la palabra en ingles (o Fin para finalizar): ");
            fflush(stdin);

            if(fgets(palabras[i].ingles, PAL, stdin))
                palabras[i].ingles[strcspn(palabras[i].ingles, "\n")] = 0;

            if(palabras[i].ingles == "Fin")
                fin = 0;
            else{
                printf("\nIntroduzca su traduccion en espanol: ");
                fflush(stdin);

                if(fgets(palabras[i].espanol, PAL, stdin))
                    palabras[i].espanol[strcspn(palabras[i].espanol, "\n")] = 0;
            }
        }

        i++;

    } while(i < MAX || !fin);
}
```

En la ejecución del programa, escribo Fin y es como si no entrara en la sentencia de  `if(palabras[i].ingles == "Fin")`

Comment: Y si pruebas con `while(i < MAX || fin==1)` ???

Comment: ... Investiga la funcion strcmp(char* str_1,char* str_2) que esta en el encabezado string.h

Comment: Puedes usar un if y, si se cumple ese if utilizar un break